# Power series problems

Tags: power-series

How can I find the power series expansion of following functions. I don't have any idea, these seem intimidating. Please help how to proceed.

1. $(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^a$
2. $\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{x}}$

Comment: Have you tried just slugging it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of the first expression, call it $u(x)$, is
$$
u'(x)=\frac{a(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^a}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$
so that
$$
u'(x)=au(x)(1+x^2)^{-\frac12}
$$
The binomial power series $(1+x^2)^{-1/2}=\sum c_mx^{2m}$ is known so that this last equation becomes, after comparing coefficients of equal degree, a triangular linear system for the power series coefficients of $u(x)$,
$$
u_k=\frac{a}{k}\sum_{0\le m<k/2} u_{k-1-2m}c_m
$$

---

For the second equation note that by binomial identities
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x}}{x}}=(1+\sqrt{1+x})^{-1/2}
$$
which possibly will simplify the expansion, it should be possible to apply similar steps as above.